# C# TrimStart weird behaviour

Tags: c#

Hey guys just wanted to understand something here.

I have this code:

```
        var testString = "DA DDDLY DO:DAXS      D/B#BTN A   TIME/DTE:0027/01NOV";
        var testTrimStart = testString.TrimStart("DA ".ToCharArray());
```

testTrimStart outputs:

> LY DO:DAXS      D/B#BTN A   TIME/DTE:0027/01NOV

Could someone explain why

> DA DDD

is removed.

I could understand if it was

> DA DA DDDLY DO....

I understand it's an array of type CHAR that it's searching for. But should it not be searching and replacing

> "DA "

throughout the string?

Here's the [.NET FIDDLE](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7hSBUx) Link

Comment: I think you have Trim and Replace mixed up. Trim only cuts the start and end of the string. Replace searches the whole string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You said:

- Trim away every character from the start of the string that is either a `'D'`, a `'A'`, or a space.

The behavior of `TrimStart` is documented in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.string.trimstart?view=netframework-4.7.1):

> Removes all leading occurrences of a **set of characters** specified in an array from the current String object.

*(my emphasis)*

Basically the TrimStart method is this in pseudocode:

```
if first character of string is either a 'D', a 'A', or a space
    then remove that character
    and repeat this algorithm for the next character (which is now the first)
```

The actual implementation is more optimal than this but this is how you could sum it up.

---

If you meant this:

> Remove this specific substring from the start of the string if it is present

Then there are 2 ways of doing that:

- Use a regex

  ```
  Regex.Replace(testString, "^DA ", string.Empty);
  ```
- Look for it yourself using substring and comparison

  ```
  if (testString.StartsWith("DA "))
      testString = testString.Substring(3); // 3 == length of "DA "
  ```

If you this:

- A simple replace

then you have no guarantee that the replacement will occur at the very start of the string.

Comment: I think it just clicked. The keyword is LEADING occurences. but that still doesn't explain the single D letter when we're looking for "DA ", isn't it looking for 3 characters, or is it looking for any of the three since it's a CHAR array.

Comment: It is *look at each character in the string to replace in in turn*, and if that character is either a D, an A or a space, it is trimmed away and the "look at each character" loop goes on to the next character. It is not a substring replacement, it is a **character** trim function.

Comment: Well there we have it. any of the three since it's a CHAR array lol

Comment: Thanks guys for clearing it up. I was stumped for a little bit!